# FindRoot: equation with integral on parametric domain

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

Writing:

```
AbsoluteTiming[

 Ac = ImplicitRegion[{-200 < y - yc < 0, 
                      100 + y - yc < 4/3 x < 100 - y + yc, 
                      Cos[a] y - x Sin[a] > 0}, 
                     {x, y}];

 eqn = {(Integrate[y, {x, y} ∈ Ac] + 1920 π (3 yc - 395)) sc + 20 10^3 yc,
        (Integrate[x y, {x, y} ∈ Ac] + 144000 π (3 yc - 395)) sc,
        (Integrate[y^2, {x, y} ∈ Ac] + 1920 π (64350 + yc (3 yc - 790))) sc 
        - 10^3 (10^4 - 20 (yc - 200/3)) yc};

 FindRoot[eqn, {{a, 0.9, 0.9, 2 π}, {yc, 100, 0, 200}, {sc, 15, 0, 30}}]

 ]
```

I get:

> {315.452, {a -> 1.45833, yc -> 128.483, sc -> 13.8217}}

It's clear that the time required for the calculation is excessive. How can the code be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In under 5 seconds on my old laptop; you are using numerics in `FindRoot`, so use numerics everywhere:

```
f[a_, yc_, sc_?NumericQ] := {
  (NIntegrate[ y  Boole[y Cos[a] > x Sin[a]], {y, -200 + yc, yc}, {x, 3/4 (100 + y - yc), 3/4 (100 - y + yc)}] +  1920 π (3 yc - 395)) sc + 20 10^3 yc,
  (NIntegrate[x y Boole[y Cos[a] > x Sin[a]], {y, -200 + yc, yc}, {x, 3/4 (100 + y - yc), 3/4 (100 - y + yc)}] + 144000 π (3 yc - 395)) sc,
  (NIntegrate[y^2 Boole[y Cos[a] > x Sin[a]], {y, -200 + yc, yc}, {x, 3/4 (100 + y - yc), 3/4 (100 - y + yc)}] + 1920 π (64350 + yc (3 yc - 790))) sc - 10^3 (10^4 - 20 (yc - 200/3)) yc
  };

FindRoot[f[a, yc, sc], {{a, 1, 0.9, 2 π}, {yc, 100, 0, 200}, {sc, 15, 0, 30}}] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {4.74802, {a -> 1.45833, yc -> 128.483, sc -> 13.8217}} *)
```